# Output the value of textboxes within a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I'm trying to figure out how to print the values of generated textboxes.
The textboxes are generated according to the number given by the user.
I then want to access the values in order to print them in a MessageBox.
Though this isn't my final intention with the code it will lead me on the way to where I need to be.

Here is the code:

```
public Class Main
 {
int tester;
      public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //checks textBoxes

        if (!Int32.TryParse(locationText.Text, out tester))
        {
            locationError.Show();
            return;
        }
      int locations = tester;

      //adding lists
       Lists lists = new Lists();
       lists.MakeLabelList(tester);
       List<TextBox> listScreens = lists.MakeScreenList(tester);

       int screenX = 150;
        int shirtX = 230;
        int doublesX = 310;
        int screenY = 15;



       for (int loc=0; locations > 0 ; loc++)
       {

         //adding Screens

           listScreens[loc].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(screenX, screenY);
           listScreens[loc].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
           panel2.Controls.Add(listScreens[loc]);
           locations--;
           screenY = screenY + 25;

           PrintSubmit.Show();
           PrintSubmit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(shirtX-60, screenY);
           panel2.Controls.Add(PrintSubmit);

           submitCancel.Show();
           submitCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(shirtX+35, screenY);
           panel2.Controls.Add(submitCancel);

       }
    }

 }
```

Now For the Class I use to create the list.

```
 public class Lists
{


    public List<TextBox> MakeScreenList(int tester)
    {
        List<TextBox> screenList = new List<TextBox>();
        for (int loc = 0; tester >= 1; loc++)
        {
            //Screen TextBoxes
           screenList.Add(new TextBox());
            tester--;
        }
        return screenList;
    }
}
```

Now I have a Submit Method where I want to use what is entered in the textboxes.

```
 private void PrintSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Lists lists = new Lists();
       List<Label> listLabels = lists.MakeLabelList(tester);
       List<TextBox> listScreens = lists.MakeScreenList(tester);
       List<TextBox> listShirts = lists.MakeShirtList(tester);
       List<TextBox> listDoubles = lists.MakeDoublesList(tester);



       foreach(TextBox screens in listScreens){

        MessageBox.Show(screens.Text);

       }
}
```

The Code above will give me the correct amount of MessageBoxes but they are all empty.
I have other lists in this code with labels and the text value of the labels are defined within the Class Lists(); and this works fine.

Please let me know if i need to explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When button print clicked, your program creates new list of empty textbox apart from those shown in the form. That's why you get empty strings in MessageBox.

You need to either make `listScreens` variable in `button1_Click` global (put the declaration out of method, could be under `int tester;`). Then in `PrintSubmit_Click` print from global `listScreens` instead of creating new variable. Or second option is to iterate through `TextBoxes` in `panel2.Controls`.

Anyway, the point is don't create new textboxes to be printed. User fills textboxes on form, so find out a way get those textboxes from the form. Creating new ones will give you empty textboxes. The same way can be applied for lables and other list of textbox, so you can have a more efficient program. The program crates lables and textboxes once, and reuse it instead of recreating it every time needed.

Following is an example of using global variable to store list of textboxes :

```
public Class Main
 {
    int tester;
    List<TextBox> listScreens;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ....
        Lists lists = new Lists();
        lists.MakeLabelList(tester);
        //don't create new list, use global variable defined above
        listScreens = lists.MakeScreenList(tester);

        int screenX = 150;
        ....
    }

    private void PrintSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(TextBox screens in listScreens){
            MessageBox.Show(screens.Text);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know what I get . Thanks har07

Comment: I'll be angry if it was that easy haha